# Prove or disprove differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Prove or disprove: If $I$ is a neighborhood of $x_{0}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $f\colon I\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ then $f$ is differentiable for at least one other $x$-value in $I$.

I am really lost with this one. I think it's true but I can't go any further. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

For a counter example consider $f(x)=x^2$  if $x$ is rational and $f(x)= -x^2$ if $x$ is not rational.

Note that f(x) is differentiable  only at $x=0$